# How to calculate an angle between 2D vector and OX with numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vector

Supposing, I have a 2D numpy array link this:

```
import numpy as np
v = np.array([1, 2])
```

I want to consider it as a vector at a 2D flat, that has axis OX and OY. I am curious, is there a build-in or quite elegant way to calculate the angle between the vector and the axis OX? The angle should be from -PI to PI.

I know, I could calculate with the help of `numpy.arctan` this way:

```
def calc_phi(v):
    if v[0] > 0:
        return np.arctan(v[1] / v[0])
    else:
        if v[1] > 0:
            if v[0] < 0:
                return np.pi + np.arctan(v[1] / v[0])
            else:
                return np.pi
        elif v[1] < 0:
            if v[0] < 0:
                return -np.pi + np.arctan(v[1] / v[0])
            else:
                return -np.pi
        else:
            return 0.0
```

But it doesn't seem to be elegant, because I have to separately consider the cases x = 0, and x < 0. So I think, `numpy` probably has a special function to calculate it.

Comment: Did you try [arctan2](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`np.arctan2`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html):

```
np.arctan2(*v)
```

---

However, as the angle is from the `y-axis`:

```
   |->
   |  \   #so this is the positive direction
   |   
-------
   |
   |
```

*diagram probably won't help*

---

It's necessary to swap the arguments to make it calculate the angle from X:

```
np.arctan2(v[1], v[0])
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the function, I'm looking for. But actually I don't need the multiplication by 2. Instead, I need np.arctan2(v[1], v[0]) to have the angle from OX.